# How to run sass watch with just gulp

Tags: sass, gulp

how can I run pure gulp sass? I'd like to have installed just node modules and gulp and run some port of sass using watch. I'd like to avoid ruby version of sass. Is it possible? I run windows but i'd like the solution to be cross-platfom, which shouldn't be problem for node.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking for the seemlest and lightest solution without the needs of writing any gulp scripts, you can simply use [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) and npm scripts.

For example in your `package.json` :

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass -w ./path/to/entry-point.scss ./path/to/build.css",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3"
  }
}
```

The `-w` is for the watch feature based on your entry parameter.

Then, simply :

```
$ npm run sass
// or
$ yarn sass
```

Check the [CLI documentation](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#command-line-interface) for more informations.

I hope, it will help !